# How to display the image from root folder?

Tags: c#, iis

i am creating one folder in solution for saving images.published it in iis server.
images are succesfully saving in that folder.but how to access other users that images?
any configurations to that folder or directle we can access like http://ipaddress/sample/foldername/1.jpg is it correct or need to give any configurations?

Comment: Providing Apache is not configured to deny requests to your URL, you should be able to link directly. What have you tried?

Comment: while browsing in IE not displaying image showing bytes data.

Comment: please tell me how to browse iis published images via browser.it displaying error message like "the image htp://ipaddress/sample/images/1.jpg can't be displayed because of it conatins errors" while browsing in IE not displaying image displaying bytes data.please help me

Comment: `{image} can't be displayed because of it conatins errors` is generally an indication that the image is corrupt, or it's not actually a JPEG. Verify you can open the file, and that it's actually a JPEG.

Comment: if you want to browse using IIS try this http://blog.crowe.co.nz/archive/2006/03/18/603.aspx